# How does a ViewHolder differentiate between buttons with tags and be used in inner method onClick?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a `ViewAdapter` that has a `ViewHolder` that shows:

`-------------------------------------`

`[image] [text 1].............. [Buy!]` --> buy button changes color/font size/text name

`-------------------------------------`

`[image] [text 2].............. [Buy!]` --> buy button changes color/font size/text name

`-------------------------------------`

However, the buttons have different functionality (not yet implemented) besides just changing colors/font size/text name and I'm not sure how to differentiate between the buttons. Also, since `onClick` is an inner class, `holder` has to be final and it can't be because it's getting used so many times. Is there a way to ONLY have it change the first buy button to be grey and "purchased!" when clicked and the same for the second buy button?

```
public class StoreListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StoreRowItem> {

Context storeContext;

String android_id = Secure.getString(storeContext.getContentResolver(), 
                                     Secure.ANDROID_ID);

public StoreListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<StoreRowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.storeContext = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    Button buttonView;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    StoreRowItem storeRowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) storeContext
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.store_list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_list_image);
        holder.buttonView = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buy_button);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.buttonView.setText(storeRowItem.getBuy());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(storeRowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(storeRowItem.getImageId());
    holder.buttonView.setTag(storeRowItem.getListNum());

    holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String title = v.getTag().toString();

            if (title.equals("1")) {
                        holder.buttonView.setTextSize(12);
                        holder.buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        holder.buttonView.setText("Purchased!");
            }

            else if (title.equals("2")) {
                        holder.buttonView.setTextSize(12);
                        holder.buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        holder.buttonView.setText("Purchased!");
            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing the UI work in the button click, update whatever purchased state you need to, then call `notifyDataSetChanged`. This way your `getView` method will be called again for that row and you can update the view according to your modified state.

For example:

```
if (storeRowItem.isPurchased()) {
    holder.buttonView.setTextSize(12);
    holder.buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    holder.buttonView.setText("Purchased!");
} else {
    // Make sure to set your view state back to the non-purchased defaults, because of view recycling
    holder.buttonView.setTextSize(14);
    holder.buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.White);
    holder.buttonView.setText(storeRowItem.getBuy());
}

holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getItem(position).setPurchased(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

You'll have to mark the `position` argument as `final` for this to work. Obviously this isn't quite drop-in, but it should give you an idea of what you can do.

Also: make sure to move your text size, strings etc out into resource files. Specifying text size like you're doing is bad practice - what happens when text size 12 is visibly smaller on a high DPI device than a low one? Or you want to offer a language other than English? Have a good read of the [Resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. What else would I need to do to this? Sorry, I'm not familiar with ArrayAdapters. Where should the if/else block go?

Comment: Right above where you've got your `setOnClickListener` call now. So you'd have the part where you set up your view holder, the part where you update view state based on current object state, and then the part where you set your click listener - you already have these 3 sections. Also, it's important to set the default state (that's the `else`), because otherwise it re-uses the existing view state when it receives a recycled view - which can result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, the text seems to barely appear. The default color for all text is white (as set in the XML). Do you know why it looks like this? http://i.imgur.com/HMgUASE.png

Comment: Because you're setting the size in code, and not using SP values. I'd recommend just setting the size in XML, such as `android:textSize="12sp"`, adjusting it and checking it in the GUI editor until it's a size you're happy with. Have a read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) for details on what it means to specify text size in "sp" values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the buttonView from the holder, get it from the view that is passed to the onClick method.

```
holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final ButtonView buttonView = (ButtonView) v;
        String title = v.getTag().toString();

        if (title.equals("1")) {
                    buttonView.setTextSize(12);
                    buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    buttonView.setText("Purchased!");
        }

        else if (title.equals("2")) {
                    buttonView.setTextSize(12);
                    buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    buttonView.setText("Purchased!");
        }

    }
});
```